# Powerpoint - how can I make sure custom fonts and formatting hold when sending

Tags: powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint that uses custom fonts which I want to send to someone. Right now when I send the PowerPoint to a computer without the fonts installed, they will default back to other font types. This ruins the formatting on many of the slides.

Is it possible to embed the fonts so they can open and view the PowerPoint file without having to download the fonts themselves?

Comment: PowerPoint is not a portable document format, export to PDF if you want portability. Otherwise use this tip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-NHFKjq8fY

Comment: @alfC that video is perfect thank you

Comment: Nicely done video, indeed. One update: as of a recent update, PowerPoint 365/Mac can both use embedded fonts and embed them.